# undefined reference to `_doFormatMessage' using i586-mingw32msvc-gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am using:Linux kali 3.18.0-kali3-586 #1 Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) i686 GNU/Linux

I have executed this below command:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc 1197.c  -lws2_32  -o 1197.exe
```

get output:

```
1197.c:112:43: warning: multi-character character constant
1197.c: In function ‘ExplorerExecution’:
1197.c:112: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
1197.c:115:43: warning: multi-character character constant
1197.c:115: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
1197.c: In function ‘main’:
1197.c:173: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
/tmp/ccAfLCQw.o:1197.c:(.text+0x3d6): undefined reference to `_doFormatMessage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

header of this 1197.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

Please give any suggestion why i had this:

```
/tmp/ccAfLCQw.o:1197.c:(.text+0x3d6): undefined reference to `_doFormatMessage'
```

Comment: That is the typical effect of a library incompatibility. Your application expects the library to define some  label which it does not. Therefore the label cannot be resolved. This suggests that you are linking a wrong library version.

Comment: @arkascha , i already use lws2_32, still getting this error. I could not understand which library to add. Please suggest me the library file.

Comment: I wrote the wrong version of a library, not a wrong library. But indeed you are right, it might also be some library you are missing. I have no idea about such MS-Windows stuff, though. Sorry.